# using java decompiler jd-gui and getting // INTERNAL ERROR //

Tags: java, android, dex2jar

I decompiled an apk file using dex2jar and opened the resulting jar file in jd-gui. I can view almost all of the code nicely but one section - the constants - displays only `// INTERNAL ERROR //` and nothing else. Is there a way to retrieve the constants?

Comment: Which version of jd-gui and which version of Java are you running? Have you tried running `javap`? Decompiler compatibility changes with every new Java release.

Comment: Try luyten / bytecode-viewer

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Anyone passing by this question should look at this instead: https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten

Using this instead of jd-gui, I was able to successully view all code which showed as INTERNAL ERROR on jd-gui.

You can also try Jadx: https://github.com/skylot/jadx

Comment: Luyten doesn't allow to open directory (eg. several `.class` files in directory structure). It only works in jar files, therefore not useful to me.

Comment: @TomášZato you can build a jar file yourself. Just put the whole directory structure into a zip file and rename it to jar.

Comment: OK but  jd-gui can decompile wars and the libs in it are linked. In Luyten if we put all the jar content in zip and rename to jar then we can see the classes but the jars in the lib can not be decompiled.

Comment: Jadx works very well. Luyten didn't display the lambda classes which was viewable in Jadx and somewhat in JD-GUI.

Comment: luyten doesn't have a type search (ctrl+T) which is essential
And jadx didn't decompile just showed a node with Source Code and nothing more

Comment: They both display unicode character(in my case, Chinese) as \uxxxx but I want to see the real character. jd-gui doesn't has this problem. By the way, When I use jd-gui 1.4, it has this "internal error" problem but when I switch back to o.3.6 it works well. Does anyone know why? (note: I'm using Win7 64bit)

Comment: Mostly, it works well unless there is some java version issue.

Comment: JD-GUI wasn't able to handle files of mine that had a large range of FX bindings and lambdas - Luyten was the way to go

Comment: I downloaded the jar directly from https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten/releases and it works like a charm! Thanks!!

Comment: I think Luyten has a shortcoming. I tried opening a war file and in its tiny taskbar it says File is too large : 76.5 MB

Comment: Luyten worked like a charm! JD-GUI could not do it for me. Big upvote!

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problem by installing Java Jdk 64Bit "Java SE Development Kit 8u111"

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue and it worked after updating Java Decompiler.

Please download latest version.
http://java-decompiler.github.io/

Comment: Please put some effort to explain your answer. That would really help others who are troubleshooting similar problems