# Extracted Apk file shows Internal error when opened the java file

Tags: java, android, dex2jar

I have Extracted the apk file using dex2jar,when i opened the java source files in the jd-gui (java decompiler) it's showing Internal Error.How to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried the live demo of JD-GUI : http://jd.benow.ca/ ? I don't know why, but sometimes, the software on your computer does not work but the live demo works.

Comment: I am able to see the R file but problem is with mainactivity file@gahfy

Comment: In the woftware or in the live demo ?

Comment: I have downloaded all the necessary tools when i open the source files through jd-gui only few files showing Internal error.

Comment: @gahfy yes it works with live demo thanks gahfy

Comment: You can use either jadx, or luyten. Furthermore, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643825/using-java-decompiler-jd-gui-and-getting-internal-error